# jwplayer -> metadata.bandwidth, FPS, QoE

Tags: jwplayer, frame-rate, jwplayer7

Can anybody help me out please?

whats the value of this `metadata.bandwidth`? kbps (kilobit per second?)

Also, how can I get the FPS and the QOE (in percent) of a stream? I cant find any iformation on this in the jwplayer API :-(

Many many thanks in advance.

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

`metadata.bandwidth` gives you current download speed in bits per second.

FPS is tied to the video file itself and won't be returned via the API.

In terms of QOE, what specifically are you looking for? bufferPercent is available via the API: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#buffer

Comment: thanks. you mean bits per second or kilobits per second? bits would be very as I have between 70000-120000.

Answer (score 0):

`metadata.bandwidth` is not a documented feature supported in jwplayer. It's not available and would impossible to implement in all browsers for all types of playback.

Listen to the 'visualQuality' event to get updates on the current quality of video playing with adaptive bitrate streams - https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/#jwplayeronvisualquality

FPS is also not available, but in an ideal scenario you know the fps of each quality in your HLS or DASH streams.

If you are interested in browser APIs that may provide some of this info in the future have a look at Media Capabilities: https://github.com/WICG/media-capabilities